# Does $P(X=0) \leq P(Y=0)$ hold?

Tags: probability

Consider two random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $E(X) = E(Y)$ and $Var(X) \leq Var(Y)$. Furthermore, we assume that $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative and integral valued. From Chebychev's inequality one easily deduces $P(X=0) \leq \frac{Var(X)}{E(X)^2}$ (and the same statement for $Y$, of course).
This 'suggests' that $P(X=0) \leq P(Y=0)$, but does this always hold?

Comment: erm, your random variable is discrete or continuous?

Comment: @Lost1: it says integral valued.

Comment: sorry, should have read more carefully.

Comment: no problem! $\mbox{}$

Comment: If you take an $X$ with equality in the estimate and $Y$ with a strict inequality in the estimate, that should be a counterexample (you can stretch the variances to be equal)

Comment: I'm not sure how you have come to the inequality $P(X = 0) \le \frac{Var[X]}{E[X]^2}$. Chebyshev's inequality inequality states $P(|X - E[X]| \ge t) \le \frac{Var[X]}{t^2}$. Letting $t = E[X]$ gives $P(|X - E[X]| \ge E[X]) \le \frac{Var[X]}{E[X]^2}$ which implies $1 - P(0 \le X \le 2E[X]) \ge \frac{Var[X]}{E[X]^2}$.

Comment: Following from that you could use that $P(x < 0) = 0$ to simplify the last result to $1 - P(X \le 2E[X]) \le \frac{Var[X]}{E[X]^2}$ and hence $P(X \ge 2E[X]) \le \frac{Var[X]}{E[X]^2}$.

Comment: You don't even need that X is non-negative. Just choose $t = E(X)$, then $P(X = 0) \leq P(|X - E(X)|\geq E(X)) \leq \frac{Var(X)}{E(X)^2}$.

Comment: And how exactly did you conclude that $P(X = 0) \le P(|X - E[X]| \ge E[X])$?

Comment: Well, you have $\{X=0\} \subset \{|X-E(X)| \geq E(X)\}$. If X is zero then the inequality $|X-E(X)| \geq E(X)$ obviously holds!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a counterexample:

Let $X  = 0$ probability $0.99$ and $=100$ with probability $0.01$

Let $Y = 0$ with probability $0.98$ $=1$ with probability $19/999$ and  $=1000$ with probability $0.02-19/999$

mean is the same, variance of $Y$ is about 1000, variance of $X$ is about 100

EDIT: user66081's comment basically sums up the intuition behind this counterexample

Answer (score 0):

This is not true in general. Suppose that the probability distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is:
Suppose $P(X=0)=P(x=4)=\frac 1n$, $P(X=2)=\frac{n-2}n$. Now, $E(X)=2$ and $\sigma_X=2^2+2^2=8$.
We can also take $Y$ to be $P(Y=1)=P(Y=3)=m$ and $P(Y=2)=\frac{n-2m}n$. Then $E(Y)=0$ and $\sigma_Y=2m$.
When $m\geq 4$, we have $\sigma_X\leq \sigma_Y$, $E(X)=E(Y)$ and $\frac 1n=P(X=0)\not\leq P(Y=0)=0$. Thus, this is a counterexample.